# extend a compound datatype in hdf5 fortran

Tags: data-structures, fortran90, hdf5

I'm trying to do something that should be fairly common. Write an array of a compound datatype out to an hdf5 file, extend the file and write the new values of the array out and so on. I want to do this inside a loop. I initialize my dataset to have zero length and then extend it as needed in the loop.
If the loop is 1 trip it works fine:

```
  HDF5 "mydata_1trip.h5" {
  GROUP "/" {
  DATASET "MYDATA" {
  DATATYPE  H5T_COMPOUND {
     H5T_STD_I32LE "i4_name";
     H5T_STD_I16LE "i21_name";
     H5T_STD_I16LE "i22_name";
     H5T_IEEE_F64LE "r8_name";
  }
  DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 2 ) / ( H5S_UNLIMITED ) }
  DATA {
  (0): {
        -100,
        -1,
        0,
        1e+06
     },
  (1): {
        -100,
        -1,
        0,
        1e+06
     }      }      }      }      }
```

With a 2 trip loop the dataset is correctly extended, but the 2nd write
overwrites the original data (and puts garbage in the 2nd dataset). So the problem would appear to be with the offset?

```
HDF5 "mydata_2trip.h5" {
GROUP "/" {
DATASET "MYDATA" {
  DATATYPE  H5T_COMPOUND {
     H5T_STD_I32LE "i4_name";
     H5T_STD_I16LE "i21_name";
     H5T_STD_I16LE "i22_name";
     H5T_IEEE_F64LE "r8_name";
  }
  DATASPACE  SIMPLE { ( 4 ) / ( H5S_UNLIMITED ) }
  DATA {
  (0): {
        -200,
        -2,
        0,
        2e+06
     },
  (1): {
        -200,
        -2,
        0,
        2e+06
     },
  (2): {
        107382520,
        1,
        0,
        0
     },
  (3): {
        107375576,
        1,
        0,
        4.94066e-324
     }
  }
  }
  }
  }
```

Here is the code

```
      program read_test
  USE hdf5
  USE ISO_C_BINDING
  implicit none
```

KIND parameters

```
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: int_k1 = SELECTED_INT_KIND(1) ! This should map to INTEGER*1 on most modern processors
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: int_k2 = SELECTED_INT_KIND(4) ! This should map to INTEGER*2 on most modern processors
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: int_k4 = SELECTED_INT_KIND(8) ! This should map to INTEGER*4 on most modern processors
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: int_k8 = SELECTED_INT_KIND(16) ! This should map to INTEGER*8 on most modern processors

  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: r_k4 = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(5) ! This should map to REAL*4 on most modern processors
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: r_k8 = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(10) ! This should map to REAL*8 on most modern processors
```

FILES

```
  CHARACTER(LEN=*), PARAMETER ::
 &   H5FILE_NAME="mydata.h5"
  CHARACTER(LEN=*), PARAMETER :: DATASETNAME = "MYDATA"

  type my_data
  sequence
  integer(kind=int_k4) :: i4
  integer(kind=int_k2) :: i1_2,i2_2
  real (kind=r_k8) :: r8
  end type

  integer(kind=int_k4) :: nsize=2,i
  type(my_data),allocatable :: iblock(:)


  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: RANK = 1



  TYPE(my_data), pointer :: s1(:)
  INTEGER(hid_t) :: s1_tid  ! File datatype identifier
  INTEGER(HID_T) :: file_id ! File identifier 
  INTEGER(HID_T) :: dset_id ! Dataset identifier 
  INTEGER(HID_T) :: dataspace ! Dataspace identifier 
  INTEGER(HID_T) :: memspace ! Memory dataspace identifier 
  INTEGER(HID_T) :: crp_list ! Dataset creation property identifier 


  INTEGER(hsize_t) :: DIMS(1) ! Dataspace dimensions
  INTEGER(SIZE_T) :: type_size ! Size of the datatype
  INTEGER(SIZE_T) :: compound_offset, sizeof_compound
  INTEGER(HSIZE_T), DIMENSION(1) :: chunk_dims,size
  INTEGER :: hdferr
  TYPE(C_PTR) :: f_ptr
```

Maximum dimensions

```
  INTEGER(HSIZE_T), DIMENSION(1) :: maxdims 

  INTEGER(HSIZE_T), DIMENSION(1) :: offset
  INTEGER(HSIZE_T), DIMENSION(1) :: count
```

allocate the buffers:

```
  allocate(iblock(nsize))
  dims(1) = nsize
  allocate(s1(dims(1)))
```

Initialize FORTRAN interface.

```
  CALL h5open_f(hdferr)
```

Create a new file using default properties.

```
 CALL h5fcreate_f(h5file_name, H5F_ACC_TRUNC_F, file_id, hdferr)
```

We set it initially to 0. We
can extend the dataset at each step.

```
  maxdims = (/H5S_UNLIMITED_F/)
  dims(1) = 0
  write(*,*)" dims = ",dims
```

Create the data space with unlimited dimensions.

```
  CALL H5Screate_simple_f(RANK, dims, dataspace, hdferr,maxdims)
```

Then create a dataset creation property list. The layout of the dataset
have to be chunked when using unlimited dimensions. The choice of the
chunk size affects performances, both in time and disk space. If the
chunks are very small, you will have a lot of overhead. If they are
too large, you might allocate space that you don't need and your files
might end up being too large. This is a toy example so we will choose
chunks of one line.

Modify dataset creation properties, i.e. enable chunking

```
  CALL h5pcreate_f(H5P_DATASET_CREATE_F, crp_list, hdferr)
  chunk_dims(1) = nsize
  CALL h5pset_chunk_f(crp_list, RANK, chunk_dims, hdferr)
```

Create the memory data type.

```
  CALL H5Tcreate_f(H5T_COMPOUND_F, H5OFFSETOF(C_LOC(s1(1)),
 &   C_LOC(s1(2))), s1_tid, hdferr)

  CALL H5Tinsert_f(s1_tid, "i4_name",
 &   H5OFFSETOF(C_LOC(s1(1)),C_LOC(s1(1)%i4)),
 &   h5kind_to_type(int_k4,H5_INTEGER_KIND), hdferr)
  CALL H5Tinsert_f(s1_tid, "i21_name",
 &   H5OFFSETOF(C_LOC(s1(1)),C_LOC(s1(1)%i1_2)),
 &   h5kind_to_type(int_k2,H5_INTEGER_KIND), hdferr)
  CALL H5Tinsert_f(s1_tid, "i22_name",
 &   H5OFFSETOF(C_LOC(s1(1)),C_LOC(s1(1)%i2_2)),
 &   h5kind_to_type(int_k2,H5_INTEGER_KIND), hdferr)
  CALL H5Tinsert_f(s1_tid, "r8_name",
 &   H5OFFSETOF(C_LOC(s1(1)),C_LOC(s1(1)%r8)),
 &   h5kind_to_type(r_k8,H5_REAL_KIND), hdferr)
```

Create the dataset.

```
  CALL H5Dcreate_f(file_id, datasetname, s1_tid, dataspace, 
 &   dset_id, hdferr,crp_list)
```

Close resources. The dataset is now created so we don't need the
property list anymore. We don't need the file dataspace anymore because
when the dataset will be extended, it will become invalid as it will
still hold the previous extent. So we will have to grab the updated
file dataspace anyway.

```
  call h5pclose_f(crp_list,hdferr)
  CALL h5sclose_f(dataspace, hdferr)
```

We create a memory dataspace to indicate the size of our buffer in
memory.

```
  dims(1) = nsize
  CALL h5screate_simple_f(RANK, dims, dataspace, hdferr)
```

setup the input data

```
  do i=1,2
   iblock(:)%i4 = -100*i
   iblock(:)%i1_2 = i
   iblock(:)%i2_2 = -i
   iblock(:)%r8 = 1.d6*i
```

Write data to memtype

```
   s1(:) = iblock(:)
```

We create a memory dataspace to indicate the size of our buffer in
memory. 
dims(1) is already nsize

We now need to extend the dataset. We set the initial size of the
dataset to 0, we thus need to extend it first. Note that we extend
the dataset itself, not its dataspace.

```
  size(1) = i*nsize
  CALL h5dset_extent_f(dset_id, size, hdferr)
  dims(1) = nsize
  CALL h5screate_simple_f (rank, dims, memspace, hdferr)
  CALL h5dget_space_f(dset_id, dataspace, hdferr)
  offset(1) = (i-1)*nsize ! if this is in chunks
  count(1)  = nsize

  CALL h5sselect_hyperslab_f(dataspace, H5S_SELECT_SET_F, 
 &   offset, count, hdferr)
```

Write data array to dataset

```
  f_ptr = C_LOC(s1(1))
  CALL H5Dwrite_f(dset_id, s1_tid, f_ptr, hdferr)

  CALL h5sclose_f(dataspace,hdferr)

  enddo
```

Release resources

```
  CALL H5Tclose_f(s1_tid, hdferr)
  CALL h5sclose_f(memspace, hdferr)
  CALL h5dclose_f(dset_id, hdferr)
  CALL h5fclose_f(file_id, hdferr)
  end program read_test
```

Comment: so the main problem is that CALL H5Dwrite_f(dset_id, s1_tid, f_ptr, hdferr) should be: CALL H5Dwrite_f(dset_id, s1_tid, f_ptr, hdferr, memspace, dataspace). There are a few other minor bugs also.